# ESP32 SD CARD MODULE

Tags: esp32

I want to write data to a SD card using an ESP32. However it keeps not reading the SD card, I now have tried three different modules, but all the same result. I am using this module:

[image: SD CARD MODULE]

This is the code I am using (yes partly AI generated, my excuses):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// CS (Chip Select) to a designated GPIO pin (e.g., GPIO5).
// MOSI to GPIO23.
// SCK to GPIO18.
// MISO to GPIO19.
// VCC to 3.3V.
// GND to GND.

const int chipSelect = 5; // Change this to match your SD card CS pin

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // Wait for Serial port to connect
  }

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  // Open a new file and immediately close it:
  File myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("Writing to test.txt...");
    myFile.println("Testing 1, 2, 3.");
    // Close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("Done.");
  } else {
    // If the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("Error opening test.txt");
  }

  // Re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");
    // Read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    // Close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // If the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("Error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Nothing here
}
```

Does anyone spot the problem? My PINOUT is fine I am sure. I have tried for hours

Comment: can you provide serial log?